# TextBox.LineCount always -1 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I created an textbox from code behind like this:

```
    TextBox txtPlainTxt = new TextBox();
    txtPlainTxt.Height = 200;
    txtPlainTxt.Width = 300;
    txtPlainTxt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    txtPlainTxt.Text = text;
    int lineCount = txtPlainTxt.LineCount;
```

I'm trying to get the LineCount property of a textbox but problem is that it always has the value of "-1". I guess it have something to do with that I created it from code behind and not in my xaml becouse when I create the exact same textbox in xaml, everything works fine and I get the correct number of lines in it. 
I tried to call UpdateLayout() method and also tried to call Focus() method like this:

```
txtPlainTxt.Focus();
txtPlainTxt.UpdateLayout();
txtPlainTxt.Focus();
txtPlainTxt.UpdateLayout();
```

But I still get the value of -1. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want to create this in the code behind and not in the XAML?

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because until your layout gets measured, you don't have `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`, so `LineCount` can't get calculated until that happens.

That means that you can only use `LineCount` property **after** your layout got measured & arranged.

(`UpdateLayout()` only notifies the layout engine that the layout should be updated and immediately returns.)

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    TextBox txtPlainTxt = new TextBox();

    public Window1()
    {
        txtPlainTxt.Height = 200;
        txtPlainTxt.Width = 300;
        txtPlainTxt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        txtPlainTxt.Text = "some text some text some text some text some text";

        Grid.SetRow(txtPlainTxt, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(txtPlainTxt, 0);
        gridMain.Children.Add(txtPlainTxt);

        // here it will be -1
        int lineCount = txtPlainTxt.LineCount;

        gridMain.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(gridMain_LayoutUpdated);
        txtPlainTxt.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(txtPlainTxt_LayoutUpdated);

    }

    void txtPlainTxt_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // the layout was updated, LineCount will have a value
        int lineCount = txtPlainTxt.LineCount;
    }

    void gridMain_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here it will be correct too
        int lineCount = txtPlainTxt.LineCount;
    }
}
```